# Adding Menus to two panes of a splitPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, jsplitpane

I want to  have a layout like this:

[image]

The grey areas will be two different menus.

I managed to make the split panes, but I can't seem to add the menus, here's my code:

```
package View;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSplitPaneUI;

public class TaskView extends JFrame{
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu addTask, refresh;

    private int screenHeight,screenWidth;


    public TaskView()  {


        setTitle("TASKS");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        Toolkit myScreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize = myScreen.getScreenSize();
        screenHeight = screenSize.height;
        screenWidth = screenSize.width;
        setSize(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2);
        System.out.println(screenWidth/2);
        setLocation(screenWidth/4,screenHeight/4);
        placeComponents(this.getContentPane());

    }

    private void placeComponents(Container contentPane) {

        JPanel jsp1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jsp2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Area 1");
        JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Area 2");

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        addTask = new JMenu("Add Task");
        refresh = new JMenu("Refresh");
        menuBar.add(addTask);
        menuBar.add(refresh);   

        jsp1.add(menuBar);
        jsp1.add(j1);
        jsp2.add(j2);


        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
                true, jsp1, jsp2);

       splitPane.setUI(new BasicSplitPaneUI());

        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(false);
        contentPane.add(splitPane);
        splitPane.setEnabled(false);
        setVisible(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(300);
    }

}
```

Every time I try to add a menu it makes a mess in the left panel and it dosn't look at all like a menu, how can i add the menus without it looking like shit?

Comment: The same object can not be placed in two panels at the same time. It is either in one or the other.

Comment: I'm thinking that two toolbars might work better than two menus. Is there anything a menu can do (above & beyond what a tool bar can provide) that this GUI actually needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class TaskView extends JFrame {

    public TaskView() throws HeadlessException {
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, createPanel(), createPanel());
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("MenuItem 1");
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("MenuItem 2");
        JMenuItem menuItem3 = new JMenuItem("MenuItem 3");

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Main");
        menu.add(menuItem1);
        menu.addSeparator();
        menu.add(menuItem2);
        menu.add(menuItem3);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menuBar.add(new JMenu("View"));

        panel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TaskView().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```